# finding out common words in various documents python

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a csv file which is something like this:

```
 book_store_id  book_price   name

 1              200.0        foo
 1              320.0        bar
 2              220.0        foobar
 2              280.0        foo
```

So.. this is a huge list..

Now I am trying to find out that if the input is "foo"

then since bookstore id 1 has "foo" marked lowest price, then I want to return "book_store" 1

Now How I am doing this is creating an inverted index which returns something like

```
foo:1,2 
bar:1
foobar:2
```

and so on, and then a seperate dictionary where I am maintaining the price of book in a store.. but is this the best way out to solve this out.

What is the most efficient way to solve this problem in python?

Comment: efficient how? run time? coding time? space consumption? I think inverted index and IR techniques are overkill here, since your data is structural, and I agree with @StefanoBorini: Using SQL or some other relational based system, is probably the best solution.

Comment: run time....i.e purely in Big Oh notation

Comment: why -1 score?? whats wrong with the question?

Comment: Well, not my downvote, but it's not particularly well written, and it looks like you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @StefanoBorini: Thanks for explaining.. but maybe i overlooked the obvious. Can you point me out where can I find such problems solved efficiently. I am implementing this following the inverted index methodology.thanks

Comment: I have no idea. I would just write a proper select statement. If you need it for work, just use sql. if you need it for homework, you should know from the material of your course.

Comment: Big Oh for lookup? You can't do anything better than an index.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a third data structure (python dict, or database table or whatever).

the data structures key should be the name (assuming name is unique).

The value this "name" key points at should be the minimum price.

Every time you insert a new book, or update the price of a book, look up the books minimum price in the third data structure, if it is less than the minimum price, set the new minimum price.

Don't forget, if you delete a book, or increase its price, make sure you update the minimum.
(you could add another column so each book has a boolean "is current minimum". Then on price increase you only need to update the minimum if this is true.

The problem is, then you need to find the next best minimum when you remove the old minimum.

This is where it's good to have a heapq

**python has a nice implementation of heapq** here:
http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html

Otherwise you have to loop through all values to find the new minimum upon every price increase, or you have to store the 5 best prices each time, say.

have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the amount of data you are dealing with. If the amount is not too high, then what you are doing is just fine.